# Classic Active Server Page don't need SMTP server to send email?

Tags: asp-classic

This is my first time dealing with Classic ASP, and I have some questions on sending email with Collaboration Data Objects.

In .NET, when we need to send email, we need to include the SMTP server in the email object. But in classic ASP, I found out that it doesn't require a SMTP server to send email.
(my reference : http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_send_email.asp)

My questions are:
1. Why and how the email sending with CDO doesn't need SMTP server?
2. If it doesn't need SMTP server, how the email is sent out?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it needs an SMTP server.  It just assumes there's a local one present and defaults to it unless you specify a remote one as per the bottom example on your W3Schools page