# Home Server Win 7, Error CDO.Message Using Classic ASP

Tags: email, iis, asp-classic, cdo.message

I am setting up home server on win 7 and trying to figure out how to use classic asp to send mail created from a web form as confirmation. Used to have a working script using CDO.message component, but after transferred code to my home server, this component kept giving me error messages.

Wondering what is the correct setup to use home server hosted website to send email?

Tried Setting up SMTP E-Mail from IIS using localhost, port 25; not successful.

referenced http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_send_email.asp

AND tried their sample code with updated emails, not successful

```vb
Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject="Sending email with CDO"
myMail.From="mymail@mydomain.com"
myMail.To="someone@somedomain.com"
myMail.TextBody="This is a message."
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("../configuration/sendusing")=2
'Name or IP of remote SMTP server
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("../configuration/smtpserver")="smtp.server.com"
'Server port
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("../configuration/smtpserverport")=25 
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
myMail.Send
set myMail=nothing
```

Hoping someone can show me proper steps.

Comment: Do you have an SMTP Server running on your `localhost` via port `25` or do you just expect it to work by magic?

Comment: Just to emphasize that point - See [IIS7 - post #23 - Vista and SMTP server. Where is it?](http://www.iislogs.com/steveschofield/iis7-post-23-vista-and-smtp-server-where-is-it) - excerpt *"Where is my SMTP server on Vista?  I'm not sure why more developers haven't asked this question.  
Simple, it is **not included**"* Although the article relates to Vista the same applies to Windows 7. Also see [SMTP Setup for Windows 7](http://geekswithblogs.net/ferdous/archive/2011/03/15/smtp-setup-for-windows-7.aspx)

Comment: Lankymart makes a very valid point - you probably don't have an SMtp server.  Even if you do though (as was the case with XP Pro) you're better off using a remote smtp server as per the last example on your w3s link.  Is there one which comes with your ISP, or perhaps you have a Gmail account?  A lot of servers will block emails which don't come from "whitelisted" IP addresses for obvious reasons

Comment: @Lankymart - you may be amused by the easiest 25 points I've ever earned on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400747/classic-active-server-page-dont-need-smtp-server-to-send-email/25404570#25404570

Comment: @John Yeah saw that one when it was posted. ;)